# How to draw a background image on an HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, background-image

I'm working on my first HTML5 Canvas game. I am trying to put in a background image, and I don't know how to do it. The game will change backgrounds throughout levels, but I think I understand how to make that happen. However, if I just try to draw an image, then it appears above my title text. Any ideas how to fix this? I don't think the CSS method will work, because the background will change. Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>How Well Do You Know Your Swedish?</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas width="640" height="480" id="game" style="display: block; margin-left: auto;         margin-right: auto; border: 1px solid black;" Your Browser is not compatible with this game. We recommend Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, or Opera.></canvas>
  <script>
    var game_canvas = document.getElementById("game");
    var game_context = game_canvas.getContext("2d");
    var swedishflagbg = new Image();
    swedishflagbg.src = "resources/images/swedishflagbg.png";
    swedishflagbg.onload = function() {
      game_context.drawImage(swedishflagbg, 0, 0);
    }
    game_context.fillStyle = "#000000";
    game_context.font = "35px Ubuntu";
    game_context.textAlign = "center";
    game_context.textBaseline = "top";
    game_context.fillText("How Well Do You Know Your Swedish?", 320, 0);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am new to JavaScript, and even newer to the HTML5 Canvas.

Comment: Because the background is drawn in an `onload` event, while your text is drawn _immediately_. You can put text drawing in the `onload` event too, but IMO a better solution would be to use two canvas, one for background and one for foreground, and use CSS to place them accordingly.

Comment: @Passerby: Perhaps expand your comment and post it as an answer since you've answered the question (+1). Since the background is extremely static you might use an image rather than a background canvas (mobile devices are slower at handling canvas elements, so having 1 image + 1 canvas would likely be better).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending from comment:

#### The "why":

Because the background image is drawn in an `onload` event, which will happen "later", while text is drawn *immediately*.
So the text is drawn first, and then sometimes later the image is drawn, thus causing the text to be covered.

#### The "how":

Depending on how "dynamic" the background image is, you can consider:

1. use CSS `background-image` on `cancas`/`canvas` container, and use `className`/`classList` to switch between different backgrounds;
2. put an `<img>` tag underneath the `canvas`, and change its `src` property;
3. use an additional "background" `canvas` underneath the current one, so you can draw the game content in current one, and draw the (probably not frequently-updated) background in the new one.

Credit of idea 1 and 2 goes to @markE :)

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for never respond to this until now, but I ended up using `document.getElementById("canvas").style.background = "url('images/splashscreen.png')";` to change the background of the canvas.

Comment: @Republican31 Your approach does not work also, Image is in front of text again!!

Answer (score 1):

First things:

1. Check the size of your image. It should be equivalent to the size of the canvas.
2. `context.drawImage` can also take width and height parameter for the image.

Syntax: `context.drawImage(img, x, y, width, height);`

After editing, it should look like this

```
let game_canvas = document.getElementById("game");
let game_context = game_canvas.getContext("2d");
let swedishflagbg = new Image();
swedishflagbg.src = "resources/images/swedishflagbg.png";
swedishflagbg.onload = function() {
    game_context.drawImage(swedishflagbg, 0, 0, game_canvas.width, game_canvas.height);
}
game_context.fillStyle="#000000";
game_context.font="35px Ubuntu";
game_context.textAlign="center";
game_context.textBaseline="top";
game_context.fillText("How Well Do You Know Your Swedish?", 320, 0);
```

Comment: Still image is above text with this approach!!

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who is still facing the problem of background image overlaying text (Image above text), I thought "why not drawing text inside onload function after loading bg image!?"

And it worked!! The browser (Or whatever) loads image first and load my text above image.

---

```
<canvas width="534" height="104" id="game" style="display: block; margin-left: auto;  margin-right: auto; border: 1px solid black;" Your Browser is not compatible with this game. We recommend Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, or Opera.></canvas>
  <script>
    let game_canvas = document.getElementById("game");
    let game_context = game_canvas.getContext("2d");
    let swedishflagbg = new Image();
    swedishflagbg.src = "./img/logo1.png";
    swedishflagbg.onload = function() {     
    game_context.drawImage(swedishflagbg, 0, 0, game_canvas.width, game_canvas.height);
    game_context.fillStyle = "#000000";
    game_context.font = "35px Ubuntu";
    game_context.textAlign = "center";
    game_context.textBaseline = "top";
    game_context.fillText("How Well Do You Know Your Swedish?", 320, 0);
    }
    
  </script>
```